# How to create drafts and publish only if approved in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have already built a Rails app which have a model called Product. Currently, I have an attribute named `approved` to mark the approval of a product. So when listing the products, every-time I need to use a where command to check whether approved is true or false? So my question is...

- Is there a better way to do this?
- Can I override the model's show `all` method and show only approved ones?
- Is there a good gem for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create [`scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope):

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :approved, -> { where(approved: true) } 
end
```

and use it like:

```
MyModel.approved
```